# Prove that $[x]_{R}=[y]_{R} \Rightarrow g(f(x))=g(f(y))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, equivalence-relations

> Let $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$ and $g:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be functions. And let $R$ be a equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}$, defined by:
> $$xRy \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$$
>
> For any $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ prove,
>
> $$[x]_{R}=[y]_{R} \Rightarrow g(f(x))=g(f(y))$$

My thought was,

If $[x]_{R}=[y]_{R}$ then one have $xRy$, and so $f(x)=f(y)$. The implication that is asked to prove can be writen as:
$$f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow g(f(x))=g(f(y))$$

Suppose that $f(x)=f(y) $ is true. Let $f(x)=f(y)=z \in \mathbb{N}$. So,  $g(f(x))=g(f(y))=g(z)$.

Is this proof right? Thanks.

Comment: There is no definite need to introduce $z$. Whenever two things are equal, applying any function to them gives equal result. (In fact if you have to resolve to the fact that $f(x)=z$ implies $g(f(x))=g(z)$, this is not different at all from noticing that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$)

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered in a comment:

> There is no definite need to introduce $z$. Whenever two things are equal, applying any function to them gives equal result. (In fact if you have to resolve to the fact that $f(x)=z$ implies $g(f(x))=g(z)$, this is not different at all from noticing that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$) –  Hagen von Eitzen Jan 13 at 16:22